# ExtendScript Illustrator Placed Item Name

Tags: javascript, object, adobe, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I am trying to get the name of a placed Item in Illustrator.

*this is a hardcoded placed item, in case i have one selected on my artboard*

```
var myItem = app.activeDocument.selection[0];
```

Normally I would get the name of the file like so:

```
myItem.file.name
```

But I want to get the name of a placed Item where the link (filepath) is broken.

Even if the link is broken, illustrator can still read the name of it, as you can see in the placed items window:

[image]

So how can I access that name?

Comment: I don't see a way, I guess it's not part of the AI Object Model, I might be wrong, I'm not really good with AI scripting.
If you are good with RegEx, you could try this: in your script first save a copy ai file, then delete your selection, save another ai file, then open these as file objects and look for the info where the linked files are listed (search for "filePath" in your file), isolate all the linked file strings, put them into arrays, compare the two arrays and see which element is missing from the second array. Then revert to the earlier stage of your file. Extremely hack-ish though…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your reference XMPString will help you,
this jsx snippet will find ALL filepaths of broken links, not a SELECTED item.

```js
#target "Illustrator"
var doc = app.activeDocument;
$.writeln(doc.name);
var x = new XML(doc.XMPString);
var m = x.xpath('//stRef:filePath');
if (m !== '') {
  for (var i=0, len=m.length(); i < len ; i++) {
    var link_path = m[i];
    if ( File(link_path).exists === false ) {
      $.writeln(File(link_path).fsName);
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: wow, this is pretty close to what I want. Even though I am not familiar with the XMPString and the xpath() method, it returns the broken links in xml format :) 

Now how can I get he filenames out of the xml? .. is it possible to store the doc.XMPTring in an array instead of an XML ?

Comment: What version are you using? if CC or later, change xpath expression to `x.xpath('//xmpMM:Manifest//stRef:filePath')` . and run again. Do you need filename instead of filepath? use `File(link_path).name` , and you can simply to push any array..

Comment: yes I am using CC but I solved teh problem by looping through the array for half the length. This works fine since every broken link appears to be implemented twice. I am retrieving the filename by using .split() function on the actual path and selection the last part of the splitted path string. Thank you very much.

Comment: might be more complicated than it needs to be, but I am lazy enough to keep it this way. never hcange a running system :D

Comment: One more question. is this returning every file that is linked or only the broken ones?